# Mount volume on windows 10 (weblogic image)

Tags: docker, weblogic

I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
docker run -it --name wls12213 -p 7001:7001 -p 9002:9002 -v c://Users/7508594/lcm/code/perscel-local/domain.properties:/u01/oracle/properties/domain.properties container-registry.oracle.com/middleware/weblogic:12.2.1.3
```

The result is:

> Domain Home is:  /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/base_domain I dawk:
>   warning: command line argument
>   `/u01/oracle/properties/domain.properties' is a directory: skipped The
>   domain username is blank.  The Admin username must be set in the
>   properties file.

I don't immediately see what's wrong here.
I'm running this on a company laptop on Windows 10 with Docker Desktop and filesharing enabled on the c drive.

Comment: Looks like you need to specify a user, **The Admin username must be set in the properties file**.

Comment: The user name is set. It would appear this is not possible if the target folder isn't empty... I created a new docker image where I copied the file this way and it seems to be working.